# Remove Safari/Chrome select focused shadow

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

I'm trying to remove the following shadow from a select when it's focused:

[image]

I've set:

```
select {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

HTML:

```
<select />
```

But those don't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your CSS selector and what is the HTML?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. Consider a standard `<select />` HTML component and using `select { ... }` as selector. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following style:

```
select:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Or this, for all form elements:

```
input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the solution for me was:

```
box-shadow: none !important;
```

Somehow it wasn't taking the box-shadow I've set before adding `!important`

Now it's not showing the "glow" anymore.

Thanks for the replies anyway,

Dem